# wordpress WP_Query get posts by year

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to get posts by specific years?

What I want is to show the user posts from the year 2016 AND the year 2018, NOT the year 2017. I tried this but it didn't worked:

```
WP_Query('date_query' => array(
            array(
                'year' => '2016',
            ),
            array(
                'year' => '2018',
            )
        ))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `'relation' => 'OR'` to the `date_query`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array('year' => 2016)
        array('year' => 2018)
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I have created an array with the required arguments, which in my opinion makes the code look more clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'year' => 2016,
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
            array(
                'year' => 2018,
                'compare' => '<='
            ),
            array(
                 'year' => 2017,
                 'compare' => '!='
            ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The code would be simply:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array('year' => 2016),
        array('year' => 2018)
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
));
```